# wp_enqueue_scripts

Tags: plugins, php, functions

How to remove `<link rel='stylesheet' id='geowidget-4.5-css-css'  href='https://geowidget.easypack24.net/css/easypack.css' type='text/css' media='all' />` in  only for front-page and products pages.

I tried this code:

```
function remove_font_awesome() {
  wp_dequeue_style('geowidget-4.5-css-css');
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_font_awesome', 9999);
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_font_awesome', 9999 );
```

I see still this css on all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a link element ids WP add **-css**, so you need to remove it.

May be this will help:

```
function remove_font_awesome() {
  wp_dequeue_style('geowidget-4.5-css'); // not geowidget-4.5-css-css
}
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_font_awesome', 9999);
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_font_awesome', 9999 );
```